# How to open jsp or java servlet from .net

Tags: java, .net, jsp, servlets

Is there a way that I can open a jsp or call java servlet from .net and pass in parameters?

I am working on a project to process a credit card payment for a client.

On Client server side:

- client is using .net framework

- client wants to send user to my java server to process credit card payment.

- need to send over invoice #, customer id, return url to my java jsp or servlet

On my java server side:

- get the parameters, display a page for user to enter payment info and process credit card payment

- return a status code using the provided return url

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need HTTPClient class in .net ?? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A servlet exposes a url to the web you can call servlet using this url . you should use a post method as the information you want to send is credit card information then fetc the reply from that servlet in .net and process it. Lemme know if you need further clarification

Comment: Yes please provide me further clarification. No credit card will be passed in the url just customer id and invoice number. user will then be sent to my server to enter in credit card info which will be https. I need to understand how to pass large amount of information in the url. for example the customer id can be up to 50 characters long and so can the invoice number and returning url. thanks